Adding Drainage beside AC and Utilities
I am looking for a way to control my drainage in the area seen in the Imgur pictures below. I'm not entirely sure what to do about it, especially with the utilities all being in that area. This is the side of my single family home on crawlspace.
Any advice?
https://imgur.com/a/5ZUpPll

A simple/easy solution is to make sure of the grade slopes down from the house.  Also make sure any near downspouts drain far enough away

Ignore previous comment, sloping the grade is a major task, and investigate where the water comes from and block it. You have sandy ground so digging trenches should be easy for a french drain pipe. The power conduits should be at least 16 inches deep so no problem with drain on top of it

Huh? Surface grading is more work than excavating and backfilling a trench for a french drain and the pipe needed to daylight it?
